# File Write : String to Bytes

Tags: java, file, file-io, java-io

I want to write string/Char data as bytes in a file.I want this conversion happen internally in IO.* classes. I do not want to use getBytes() method on string.

I tried following two Programs but both are writing data as Character . And when i open the file in notepad i can read these characters. How can i store my data as bytes ?

```
     import IO.FileWrite;

         import java.io.*;

        public class CharToChar {

private final String data;

public CharToChar(String data){
    this.data = data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final CharToChar charToChar = new CharToChar("I am Manish");
    charToChar.write();
}

private void write() throws IOException {
    final File file = new File("CharToChar.txt");
    final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    final BufferedWriter bufferdWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferdWriter.write(this.data);
    bufferdWriter.close();

}
  }


     import java.io.DataOutputStream;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
       import java.io.IOException;

       public class WriteStringAsBytesToFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strFilePath = "WriteStringAsBytes.txt";

    try
    {
        //create FileOutputStream object
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);

  /*
   * To create DataOutputStream object from FileOutputStream use,
   * DataOutputStream(OutputStream os) constructor.
   *
   */

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        String str = "This string will be written to file as sequence of bytes!";

   /*
    * To write a string as a sequence of bytes to a file, use
    * void writeBytes(String str) method of Java DataOutputStream class.
    *
    * This method writes string as a sequence of bytes to underlying output
    * stream (Each character's high eight bits are discarded first).
    */

        dos.writeBytes(str);

    /*
     * To close DataOutputStream use,
     * void close() method.
     *
     */

        dos.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
    }

}
   }
```

Note - > JAVA docs says 
          OutputStreamWriter
An OutputStreamWriter is a bridge from character streams to byte streams:
 * Characters written to it are encoded into bytes using a specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have the wrong notion about writing as bytes/chars. Characters, are just representations of byte data. This representation is decided on the bases of [Character Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) type. Look at the following code:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    os.write("This is byte date".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.close();
```

If you open your file after running the above snippet, you'll notice the same string in the file. Your file always has data in bytes. The bytes are read by your text editor and encoded based on its default character encoding, usually *UTF-8* but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if any of java IO classes can do this, and I see that you don't want to use `getBytes()`, but if you decide to go the `getBytes()` way, then you can modify your `write()` method in your first example to something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CharToChar {

    private final String data;

    public CharToChar(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    private void write() throws IOException {       
        OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("CharToChar.txt"));
        fos.write(Arrays.toString(this.data.getBytes()).getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final CharToChar charToChar = new CharToChar("I am Manish");
        charToChar.write();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems quite odd, as converting a String to bytes is the job of the `toBytes` method which you do not want to use.... but you can serialize any Java Object, including Strings, then save it to a File as follows:

```
    try ( ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream( "CharToChar.txt" ) ) ) {
        // write any object to a file
        oos.writeObject( "I am Manish" );
        // another option, works for Strings and makes the String pretty much un-readable
        oos.writeBytes( "hello world" );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the use of      OutputStreamWriter     and InputStreamReader ? I read these classes are used as Adapters for Char to Byte

Comment: OutputStreamWriter is used to write chars to a stream, using a certain character encoding. Same for InputStreamReader, but for reading... ObjectOutputStream (that I used above) doesn't care about encoding, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeByte(int) for how chars are converted to bytes. You just use a sub-class of DataInput to read back the chars written with DataOutput.